# Calling a class from a button on an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, onclick

My page just seems to refresh. I cannot call the `LottoTest()` class onclick.

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Draw.aspx.cs" Inherits="Lotto.Draw" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>Welcome to the Lotto draw</h1>
        <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="DRAW" OnClientClick="LottoTest()" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Draw.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Lotto
{
    public partial class Draw : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        public void LottoTest()
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> numbers = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            Random generator = new Random();
            while (numbers.Count < 6)
            {
                numbers[generator.Next(1, 49)] = 1;
            }

            string[] lotto = numbers.Keys.OrderBy(n => n).Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();

            foreach (String _str in lotto)
            {
                Response.Write(_str);
                Response.Write("<br/>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are making a client request. Change OnClientClick to OnClick (without the brackets).

Then change your method signature to:
`public void LottoTest(object sender, EventArgs e)` instead of `public void LottoTest()`

Comment: Brilliant! :)  what is the purpose of the object sender, eventArgs e ?

Comment: sender is the object that invoked the event (i.e. the button you clicked on the page) and the e represents any arguments that are associated with the object that invoked the event (i.e. in a GridView, e could let you access information for the row you are working with, such as e.Row.CommandArgument).

Answer (score 2):

**Remove OnClientClick from markup and use OnClick**

Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>Welcome to the Lotto draw</h1>
        <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="DRAW" OnClick="LottoTest" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Add sender and eventargs as parameters to your method**

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Lotto
{
    public partial class Draw : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        public void LottoTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> numbers = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            Random generator = new Random();
            while (numbers.Count < 6)
            {
                numbers[generator.Next(1, 49)] = 1;
            }

            string[] lotto = numbers.Keys.OrderBy(n => n).Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();

            foreach (String _str in lotto)
            {
                Response.Write(_str);
                Response.Write("<br/>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```